# Solr - facet by day of week

Tags: solr

On Solr, I would like to get facets of a field date but according to a day of the week,
for example, if I have 3 records with the following values on the date field:

1. 16/11
2. 22/11
3. 23/11

I would like to get the following facet:
Sunday: 2,
Monday: 1

Is it possible?

Comment: you need to index the days along with date in a separate field...then you could be able to do the faceting on the week days

Comment: how would solr know the day on a particular day...You need to index the day along with the day

Comment: There is nothing built-in that I know of, but you could create a function that resolves a date to a day yourself and use that - or better, just index the day-of-week as a separate column and facet on that. It'll be far more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr does not having anything which could provide you the day of the week based on the date.

You need to index the weeks data in a separate field.
Where your fields would be holding the values like SUNDAY, MONDAY etc..

Once you have this field and indexed the data in solr.
Then you could be able to achieve the faceting based on the weeks.